# Does the main thread 'always' run in a ruby web server, like Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, sinatra

When you launch a thread from within a web request handler - does the thread continue to run as long as the server is running?

Similar to [Thread.join blocks the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481866/thread-join-blocks-the-main-thread) but could you not call join and have all the threads complete on their own schedule, likely well after the web request handler has returned an http response to the browser?

Comment: I just tested on ruby 1.9, and I can get a thousand threads working at once, launching 100 at each hit to the server. See code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works fine for me - tested on OS X local machine I was able to get 1500+ real threads running with thin and ruby 1.9.2. On Heroku cedar stack, I can get about 230 threads running before I get an error when creating a thread.

In both cases all the threads seem to finish when they are supposed to - 2 minutes after launching them. '/' is rendered in about 60 ms on Heroku, and then the 20 threads run for 2 minutes each.

If you refresh / a few times, then wait a few minutes, you can see the threads finishing. The reason I tested for 2 minutes was that heroku has a 30 second limit on responses, cutting you off if you take more than that amount of time. But this does not seem to effect background threads.

```
$threadsLaunched = 0
$$threadsDone = 0

get '/' do
  puts "#{Thread.list.size} threads"
  for i in 1..20 do
      $threadsLaunched = $threadsLaunched + 1
      puts "Creating thread #{i}"
      Thread.new(i) do |j|
          sleep 120
          puts "Thread #{j} done"
          $threadsDone = $threadsDone + 1
      end
   end
  puts "#{Thread.list.size} threads"
  erb :home
 end
```

(home.erb)

```
   <div id="content">

<h1> Threads launched <%= $threadsLaunched.to_s %> </h1>
<h1> Threads running <%= Thread.list.count.to_s %> </h1>
<h1> Threads done <%= $threadsDone.to_s %> </h1>

 </div> <!--  id="content" -->
```

Answer (score -1):

Once your main thread exits, all the other ones are forcefully destroyed too and the process exits.

```
Thread.new do
  # this thread never exists on its own
  while true do
    puts "."
    sleep 1
  end
end

sleep 5
```

Following this example, once the main thread ends, the printing thread will end too without "completing" its work. You have to explicitly `join` all background threads to wait for their completion before exiting the main thread.

On the other hand, as long as the main thread runs, other threads can run as long as they want. There is no arbitrary restriction to the request/response cycle. Note however, that in the "original" Rubies, threads are not really concurrent but are subject to the GIL. If you want true concurrency (as to use multiple core on your computer with different threads), you should have a look at either JRuby or Rubinius (2.0-preview) which both offer true concurrent threads.

If you just want to take things out of the request cycle to handle later, the green threads in 1.8 and OS-native-but-GILed threads in 1.9 are just fine though. If you want more scalability, you should have a look at technologies like [delayed_job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) or [Resque](https://github.com/blog/542-introducing-resque) which introduce persistent workers for background jobs.

Comment: Yes but a server is always running the main thread - until someone kills the server.

Comment: @TomAndersen then it seems I misunderstood your original question. I amended my answer.

Comment: As far as I know Rubinius has true threads in the Rubinius 2.0 Preview Release but not in the current 1.2.4 version.

Comment: @JonasElfström Yeah, you are right. I just haven't used the 1.x version in ages :) That said, for most people seeking an alternative implementation, JRuby is probably more appealing anyway...