# Fork a child process, and capture any stdout and stderr?

Tags: ruby, fork, parent-child, stdout, stderr

My below code example runs a command, e.g., `ls <file>` and captures stdout and stderr ( as well as the process exit status ).

However, if for example the command were to hang, then the ruby program will be "stuck" waiting for the command to finish, ( this can be seen for example if running `sleep`).

To avoid that possibility, I think what I need to do is `fork` a child process, ( so any "stuck" child process will not keep the ruby program "waiting" ).

However, I'm not sure how to capture the stdout and stderr from a forked child process, is this even possible ?

( for *reasons* I'd also like to be able to do this within the ruby std libs and not have dependency on any extra gem/s. 
  Also, this is just for ruby, *not* rails )

**edit**: To help clarify - 
Trying to understand if there is a way to fork a child process, ( so there is no blocking until the child is done ), *and* still have the ruby program capture the stdout, stderr when the child process exits.

```
#!/bin/env ruby

require 'open3'
require 'logger'

logger = Logger.new('./test_open3.log')
files = ['file1','file2','file3']

files.each do |f|
  stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3("ls #{f}")
  logger.info(stdout)
  logger.info(stderr)
  logger.info(status)
end
```

Comment: But `stdout`, `stderr`, and `status` can't have meaningful values until the child is done.

Comment: Open3.capture3 will block until the child is done.

Comment: @twenty20, can you tell us what your program is doing that isn't working?

Comment: @MichaelChaney I think the point is the OP wants a way to **not** block until the child is done.

Comment: Yes, just trying to understand if there is a way to fork a child process, ( so there is no blocking until the child is done ), *and* still have the ruby program capture the stdout, stderr when the child process exits

Comment: Yes, I think you're correct.  In that case, this probably is helpful: https://medium.com/zendesk-engineering/running-a-child-process-in-ruby-properly-febd0a2b6ec8

Comment: @twenty20, you might also use threads to capture the output.  Your program will no longer be sequential since the subprocess will continue running alongside your main process.  You'll have to figure out a way to know when the subprocess is finished and harvest/use the output.  It's a very different way of programming.

Comment: @MichaelChaney  Thanks, I saw the medium page you linked to before, unless I'm mistaken that doesn't seem to offer a solution that prevents the potential for blocking. Your threads suggestion sounds interesting, I will dig into that, that sounds like the kind of thing that might provide the kind of solution I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion in the comments to use threads, I found that this gave me what I was looking for:

```
#!/bin/env ruby

require 'open3'
require 'logger'
require 'thread'

logger = Logger.new('./test_threads_open3.log')
files = ['file1','file2','file3']
threads = []

files.each_with_index do |f, i|
  threads << Thread.new(f, i) do
    puts "Thread #{i} is running"
    stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3("ls #{f}")
    logger.info(stdout)
    logger.info(stderr)
    logger.info(status)
   end
 end
threads.each { |t| t.join }
```

This creates an array of threads each with the block of code, and then last line, each thread in the array is run.

It probably requires some extra code to manage and limit the number of threads that can be run at a time, so as to be safer, maybe by using a queue/worker feature.

( This post also touches on the topic of the `join` method - [Thread.join blocks the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481866/thread-join-blocks-the-main-thread) )